# cron with whenever gem not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, thinking-sphinx, whenever

**I am using thinking sphinx for search.It searches properlt but the problem was whenever i add new records i have to do rake thinking_sphinx:index manually.So to run it automatically i am using whenever gem with cron but still its not happening automatically,Either i have to do**

rake thinking_sphinx:index

or

whenever -w to create index automatically

Following is the code of config/schedule.rb :

```
every 10.minutes do
  rake "thinking_sphinx:index", :environment => :development
end

every :reboot do
  rake "thinking_sphinx:start",:environment => :development
end
```

when i do crontab -l i get following :

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: store
@reboot /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/newsvn/alumnicell && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake thinking_sphinx:start --silent'

0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/newsvn/alumnicell && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake thinking_sphinx:index --silent'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: store
```

What and where is the problem that this not working?

**Also i changed environment to development.by default it was production.what is the difference in these 2?**

Answer (score 0):

You can assign log file to track errors, then post it here.

Also I advise to set `:environment` globally.

Try this code:

```
set :environment, :development
set :output, 'tmp/whenever.log'

every 10.minutes do
  rake "thinking_sphinx:index"
end

every :reboot do
  rake "thinking_sphinx:start"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to use thinking sphinx's delta indexes instead of using whenever cron jobs to rebuild thinking sphinx every 10 minutes.

As it's described [here](http://pat.github.com/ts/en/deltas.html) you should just add a boolean column `delta` to your model, set `set_property :delta => true` in your `define_index` block and run `rake ts:rebuild`

That's it.